# Expo - Icon position is incorrect in Android Simulator

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Hope you are staying healthy in this pandemic period.
I have one issue in my expo app.
Please check the attached images

[iOS status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3hJi.png)

And the following is from Android

[Android status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtDRB.png)

As you can see, the position of icon for the password field is incorrect on Android.
The code is like the following.

```
    <View style={styles.footer}>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <Icon name="email-outline" size={wp('6%')} color="#00438b" style={styles.inputIcon} />
            <TextInput
                label="Email"
                style={styles.input}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <Icon name="shield-key-outline" size={wp('6%')} color="#00438b" style={styles.inputIcon} />
            <TextInput
                label="Password"
                style={styles.input}
            />
        </View>
    </View>
```

And also the style is:

```
    footer: {
        flex: 3,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderTopLeftRadius: wp('6%'),
        borderTopRightRadius: wp('6%'),
        paddingHorizontal: wp('5%'),
        paddingVertical: wp('7%'),
    },
    inputContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'space-between'
    },
    inputIcon: {
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: wp('3%'),
        alignSelf: 'center'
    },
    input: {
        flex: 5,
        marginLeft: wp('4%'),
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        padding: 0
    }
```

Please let me know the reason.
Thanks for your attention!

Comment: For now, I fixed the above error by giving flex value to the icon and input field.
I gave "flex: 1" to the icon and "flex: 11" to the input, so for now they are looking good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the above error by giving flex value to the icon and input field. I gave "flex: 1" to the icon and "flex: 11" to the input, so for now they are looking good.